# upload image to server URL

Tags: java, servlets

i have to upload an image in server location using servlet but url formating ia having some problem . i am able to upload image in local machine but when it is deployed on server with some URL like http://domain.com/folder then it is having some problem .
it is part of code from where location is read by servlet..

```
<context-param>
 <description>Location to store uploaded file</description>
 <param-name>file-upload</param-name>
  <param-value>
        F://Servers//Images//
  </param-value>
```

and it is part of code i am using to upload to server ..

```
if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
           file = new File( filePath + fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
        }else{
           file = new File( filePath + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
        }
        fi.write( file ) ;
```

when  is changed to http://domain.com/folder then it is not able to write to that location since **http:// is changed to http:/**

please help to resolve the issue...

Comment: An applet has no access to the server's filesystem.  You need to POST to a web service.

Comment: can u please explain in one or two line i am now getting ...

Answer (score 0):

you can read more on how to upload files or images using servlets here

[How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)